# Highcharts data series label. for each data point

Tags: highcharts, label

I have a line graph with data points, and each of the points have a separate label. I want to display the label in a tooltip and have a custom formatter function, but I can't manage to get the label data from the server backend into the formatter.

My data:

```
+------------------+-------+----------------------+
|       Date       | Value |        Label         |
+------------------+-------+----------------------+
| 2018-05-21 08:00 |   100 | A description        |
| 2018-05-21 08:10 |    50 | Another one          |
| 2018-05-21 08:20 |   900 | Completely different |
+------------------+-------+----------------------+
```

A really ugly way I got it to work was to serialize the labels, put it in the name field and parse it out in the formatter but that's absolutely cringeworthy.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your custom point parameter (e.g `labelDesc`) in each point object. Then, in the `series.dataLabels.formatter` function you will be able to access it by `this.point.labelDesc`. You need to return that value from the function, and that's all.
Here is the code:

```
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.label
      }
    },
    data: [{
      y: 100,
      label: 'Some label'
    }, {
      y: 50,
      label: 'Some label 2'
    }, {
      y: 900,
      label: 'Some label 3'
    }]
  }]
```

And also live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcxevy3/